# java 3D rotations not working

Tags: java, vector, matrix, 3d, rotation

I've had this old graphics project laying around (written in oberon) and since i wrote it as one of my first projects it looks kinda chaotic.
So I descided that, since i'm bored anyway, i would rewrite it in java.

Everything so far seems to work... Until i try to rotate and/or do my eye-point transformation. 
If i ignore said operations the image comes out just fine but the moment i try to do any of the operations that require me to multiply a point with a transformation matrix it all goes bad.

1. the eye point transformation generates stupidly small numbers with end coördinates like [-0.002027571306540029, 0.05938634628270456, -123.30022583847628]
   this causes the resulting image to look empty but if i multiply each point with 1000 it turns out it's just very, very small and, in stead of being rotated, has just been translated in some (seemingly) random direction.

if i then ignore the eye point and simply focus on my rotations the results are also pretty strange (note: the image auto scales depending on the range of coordinates):

1. setting xRotation to 90° only makes the image very narrow and way too high (resolution should be about 1000x1000 and is then 138x1000
2. setting yRotation to 90° makes it very wide (1000x138)
3. setting zRotation to 90° simply seems to translate the image all the way to the right side of the screen.

What i have checked so far:

1. i have checked and re-checked my rotation matrices at least 15 times now so they are (probably) correct
2. doing a test multiplication with a vector and the identity matrix does return the original vector
3. my matrices are initialized as identity matrices prior to being used as rotation matrices
4. the angles in the files are in degrees but are converted to radian when read.

Having said that i have 2 more notes:

1. a vector in this case is a simple 3 value array of doubles (representing the x, y and z values)
2. a matrix is a 4x4 array of doubles initialized as the identity matrix

When trying to rotate them i do it in the order:

1. scale (multiplying with a scale factor)
2. rotate along x-axis
3. rotate along y-axis
4. rotate along z-axis
5. translate
6. do eye-point transformation
7. then, if the point isn't already on the z-plane, project it

like so:

```
protected void rotate() throws ParseException
    {
        Matrix rotate_x = Transformations.x_rotation(rotateX);
        Matrix rotate_y = Transformations.y_rotation(rotateY);
        Matrix rotate_z = Transformations.z_rotation(rotateZ);
        Matrix translate = Transformations.translation(center.x(), center.y(), center.z());

        for(Vector3D point : points)
        {
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, scale);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, rotate_x);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, rotate_y);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, rotate_z);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, translate);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, eye);

            if(point.z() != 0)
            {
                point.setX(point.x()/(-point.z()));
                point.setY(point.y()/(-point.z()));
            }

            checkMinMax(point);
        }
    }
```

here's the code that initializes the rotation matrices if you're interested:

```
public static Matrix eye_transformation(Vector3D eye)throws ParseException
    {
        double r = eye.length();
        double teta = Math.atan2(eye.y(), eye.x());
        double zr = eye.z()/r;
        double fi = Math.acos(zr);

        Matrix v = new Matrix();

        v.set(0, 0, -Math.sin(teta));
        v.set(0, 1, -Math.cos(teta) * Math.cos(fi));
        v.set(0, 2, Math.cos(teta) * Math.sin(fi));
        v.set(1, 0, Math.cos(teta));
        v.set(1, 1, -Math.sin(teta) * Math.cos(fi));
        v.set(1, 2, Math.sin(teta) * Math.sin(fi));
        v.set(2, 1, Math.sin(fi));
        v.set(2, 2, Math.cos(fi));
        v.set(3, 2, -r);

        return v;
    }

    public static Matrix z_rotation(double angle) throws ParseException
    {
        Matrix v = new Matrix();

        v.set(0, 0, Math.cos(angle));
        v.set(0, 1, Math.sin(angle));
        v.set(1, 0, -Math.sin(angle));
        v.set(1, 1, Math.cos(angle));

        return v;
    }

    public static Matrix x_rotation(double angle) throws ParseException
    {
        Matrix v = new Matrix();;

        v.set(1, 1, Math.cos(angle));
        v.set(1, 2, Math.sin(angle));
        v.set(2, 1, -Math.sin(angle));
        v.set(2, 2, Math.cos(angle));

        return v;
    }

    public static Matrix y_rotation(double angle) throws ParseException
    {
        Matrix v = new Matrix();

        v.set(0, 0, Math.cos(angle));
        v.set(0, 2, -Math.sin(angle));
        v.set(2, 0, Math.sin(angle));
        v.set(2, 2, Math.cos(angle));

        return v;
    }

    public static Matrix translation(double a, double b, double c) throws ParseException
    {
        Matrix v = new Matrix();;

        v.set(3, 0, a);
        v.set(3, 1, b);
        v.set(3, 2, c);

        return v;
    }
```

And the actual method that multiplies a point with a rotation matrix

note: NR_DIMS is defined as 3.

```
public static Vector3D mult(Vector3D lhs, Matrix rhs) throws ParseException
    {
        if(rhs.get(0, 3)!=0 || rhs.get(1, 3)!=0 || rhs.get(2, 3)!=0 || rhs.get(3, 3)!=1)
            throw new ParseException("the matrix multiplificiation thingy just borked");

        Vector3D ret = new Vector3D();
        double[] vec = new double[NR_DIMS];

        double[] temp = new double[NR_DIMS+1];      
        temp[0] = lhs.x;
        temp[1] = lhs.y;
        temp[2] = lhs.z;
        temp[3] = lhs.infty? 0:1;

        for (int i = 0; i < NR_DIMS; i++)
        {
                vec[i] = 0;

                // Multiply the original vector with the i-th column of the matrix.
                for (int j = 0; j <= NR_DIMS; j++)
                {
                        vec[i] += temp[j] * rhs.get(j,i);
                }
        }

        ret.x = vec[0];
        ret.y = vec[1];
        ret.z = vec[2];
        ret.infty = lhs.infty;

        return ret;
    }
```

I've checked and re-checked this code with my old code (note: the old code works) and it's identical when it comes to the operations.

So I'm at a loss here, I did look around for similar questions but they didn't really provide any useful information.

Thanks :)

small addition:

if i ignore both the eye-point and the rotations (so i only project the image) it comes out perfectly fine.
I can see that the image is complete apart from the rotations.

Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, i'm currently feeling like a complete idiot. The issue was a simply logic error.
The error sits in this part of the code:

```
for(Vector3D point : points)
        {
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, scale);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, rotate_x);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, rotate_y);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, rotate_z);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, translate);
            point = Vector3D.mult(point, eye);

            if(point.z() != 0)
            {
                point.setX(point.x()/(-point.z()));
                point.setY(point.y()/(-point.z()));
            }

            checkMinMax(point);
        }
```

I forgot that, when you obtain an object from a list, it is a new instance of that object with the same data rather than a reference to it.

So what i have done is simply remove the old entry and replace it with the new one.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible mistakes I can think of:

- <del>In the constructor of Matrix, you are not loading the identity matrix.</del>
- <del>You are passing your angles in degrees instead of radians.</del>
- Your eye-projection matrix projects in another range you think? I mean, in OpenGL all projection matrixes should projection onto the rectangle [(-1,-1),(1,1)]. This rectangle represents the screen.
- Mixing up premultiply and postmultiply. Id est: I usually do: matrix*vector, where in your code, you seem to be doing vector*matrix, if I'm not mistaken.
- Mixing up columns and rows in your Matrix?

I'm going to take another look at your question tomorrow. Hopefully, one of these suggestions helps you.

EDIT: I overlooked you already checked the first two items.

Comment: as far as i'm aware all coordinates are in the -1 to 1 range

And the multiplication works when you take an identity matrix and a random vector. It should (and it does) return the original vector.

the multiplication is a double for-loop and the end vector is determined by:
    vec[i] += temp[j] * rhs.get(j,i);